# How to tell which group matched when using as a lexer?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, capturing-group

I am using a .NET Regex as a simple lexer:

```
var pattern = new Regex("(?<if>if)|(?<then>then)|(?<int>\-?\d+)...");
var tokens = pattern.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new Token { Text = m.Value, Type = TokenTypes.First(tt => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[tt].Value) });
```

After matching, I can determine the type of each token by iterating through all the named groups that represent token types and finding the one that actually matched. This seems a bit slow and clumsy, though. I'm wondering: is there a better way to find all matched groups using the .NET Regex API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see any problem with that. However, if none of your groups permit empty strings, you can use the [`Success`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property rather than checking the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the group. This is essentially what you've already got, but this seems a little more elegant in my opinion:

```
var tokens = pattern.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => new Token { Text = m.Value, Type = TokenTypes.First(tt => m.Groups[tt].Success) });
```

Or in query syntax:

```
var tokens = 
    from Match m in pattern.Matches(input)
    select new Token 
    { 
        Text = m.Value, 
        Type = TokenTypes.First(tt => m.Groups[tt].Success) 
    };
```

Comment: This approach likely has the same performance implications as my approach, though. Right? Currently, I'm finding that this process of determining the token type is actually one of the slowest parts of my lexer. Are you asserting that there is no other approach given the current Regex API?

Comment: @ChaseMedallion It would only be a marginal performance improvement at best. The only other suggestion I could make is to use group numbers rather than names, since it has to call `GroupNumberFromName` to look up each group by name every time.